# Exporting inside a function [nodejs]

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand [this code](https://github.com/mikeal/watch/blob/master/main.js) but i have a problem understanding some of the exports.

Exporting a function is clear but if you look for example inside the createMonitor function (which is exported), you will see an export to a watchTree call.

```
exports.createMonitor = function (root, options, cb) {
   if (!cb) {cb = options; options = {}}
   var monitor = new events.EventEmitter();
   monitor.stop = exports.unwatchTree.bind(null, root);

   var prevFile = {file: null,action: null,stat: null};
   exports.watchTree(root, options, function (f, curr, prev) {}
   }
```

If you look at the code, the definition of the function is also exported above.
The only i can think of is that, since inside this function there are some emit events those are exported as module emit events, but i havent seen anything in the documentation that says something like that.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `watchTree` and `unwatchTree` functions are actually exported in the same module. But as they are not standalone functions, there is no way to reference them directly. In order to avoid using such "exports referencing" scenario, you can rewrite this functions as below:

```
function watchTree(...) { /* function body */}

function unwatchTree(...) { /* function body */}

function createMonitor = function (root, options, cb) {
    if (!cb) {cb = options; options = {}}
    var monitor = new events.EventEmitter();
    monitor.stop = unwatchTree.bind(null, root);

    var prevFile = {file: null,action: null,stat: null};
    watchTree(root, options, function (f, curr, prev) {}
```

}

and then assign them to the `exports` object:

```
exports.watchTree = watchTree;

exports.unwatchTree = unwatchTree;

exports.createMonitor = createMonitor;
```

I think this scenario is a better idea and makes your code more readable, so that no one will ever get confused about the way it works, like you :)

Comment: Now i understand. They are actually defined as properties of the exports object so there is not other way to refer to them!

Thx alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a readability problem, nothing is actually being exported inside the `createMonitor` function.

```
// bind the `unwatchTree` method to the `monitor.stop` property
monitor.stop = exports.unwatchTree.bind(null, root);
...
// invoke the `watchTree` method
exports.watchTree(root, options, function(f, curr, prev) {};
```

If you look above the `createMonitor` method you will see that both `unwatchTree` / `watchTree` are being exported therefore the only way to reference them is via the `exports` object.